# JSP get referer domain

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, http-referer

With JSP how can I get the referring domain name?

If I use ${ header.host } I will get the domain of the host e.g. www.domain.com but I cannot find the equivalent for the referring domain.

I've tried ${ referer.host } and ${ referrer.host } and both do not work.

I've also tried ${request.getHeader("referer") but that returns the entire URL and not only the domain like header.host does.

Thank you

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?